# Write a \setcounter command to a file

Tags: macros, counters, auxiliary-files

I try to write a setcounter command to a file (using the `newfile` package) by something like the following

```
\addtostream{mystream}{\protect\setcounter{mycounter}{\myvariable}}
```

However, since the whole thing is protected, `\myvariable` isn't expanded and since it's value changes later in the document, the wrong value ends up in my counter. So, how can I 'unprotect' the variable here?

---EDIT---
Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}

\begin{document}
\newoutputstream{stream}
\openoutputfile{stream.file}{stream}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{6}

\addtostream{stream}{%
    \protect\setcounter{othercounter}{mycounter}%
}
\closeoutputstream{stream}

\end{document}
```

It outputs a file called `stream.file` with the content

```
\setcounter{othercounter}{mycounter}
```

but I want

```
\setcounter{othercounter}{6}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`? As far as I know, macros *are* expanded, which is the reason why `\setcounter` needs `\protect`.

Comment: @egreg I added a minimal example. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: You have to say `\themycounter` or `\arabic{mycounter}` in the `\addtostream` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `othercounter` and `mycounter` are LaTeX counters, you *can't* say

```
\setcounter{othercounter}{mycounter}
```

but, in general, you should say

```
\setcounter{othercounter}{\value{mycounter}}
```

However, for your application you need a different way, because you need the actual value of `mycounter`, not referring to the value at the time the assignment is performed. Thus

```
\addtostream{stream}{%
  \protect\setcounter{othercounter}{\arabic{mycounter}}%
}
```

is what you're looking for. The write operation will expand `\arabic{mycounter}` to the current decimal representation of the counter's value.

Answer (score 4):

`\protect` only protects the next token, not the arguments of the next token.
If `\myvariable` is not expanded, then it is perhaps not expandable (e.g. defined
by `\newcount\myvariable`. Then `\number` helps:

```
\addtostream{mystream}{%
  \protect\setcounter{mycounter}{\number\myvariable}%
 }%
```